# Add delete button for Multiselect row during editing mode UItableView

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm working with an app which has a `tableview`. I want to implement deletion for multiple rows. I have add multiple selection during editing in storyboard. But how can we track those selected row and add a delete button for these selected row during editing mode?

[image]

[image]